# Command Line HTML effect

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am looking for a HTML command line effect.

Basically, I am creating a 404 page, and I want to put in a fake command line that displays new text every second or two. Is this possible, or am I wasting my time?

I may need to do this with Flash, but I prefer not to.

Any ideas?

FS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript would be trivial, smth like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refreshparentclose()
{
 window.opener.location.reload();
 window.close();
}

-->
</script>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('refreshparentclose();', 3000);" >
<br>
Boo!


</body>
```

Replace "window.close" with generating "command" to display. Flash is overkill here.

Comment: I do not really know JS well, it refreshes every 3 seconds, right?

Comment: Yes (body onload="jsfunction..." does that). Well you should learn very basic Javascript I think, it is useful for doing basic stuff to HTML pages.